# Could a bug sting induce a human body to explode?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, diseases, explosions, insects

*The setup is similar to a funny horror movie or like Troma movies. Deaths only happen to insignificant, unnamed characters.*

However, I would like to have some plausible science back-up (maybe slightly far-fetched) of a bug sting that induces body explosion.

The bug must be realistic, similar than the world's existing ones.

The reason of explosion must be biological (e.g. toxin) similar from what real nature is capable of, but it could be more concentrated, or more quantity, more fast.

Comment: Ah, that reminds me of the facehugger from Alien.

Answer (score 6):

#### Option 1

The victim is injected with an agent (virus?) that causes the victim to somehow produce an organic explosive. After enough such compound is produced, you need to ignite the substance somehow. Also, unless it is mostly on the outside of the victim's body (in which case you might get an *outward* explosion, but the victim will just get charred), having enough oxygen for a proper explosion is going to be an issue.

I'm not sure a victim would survive this sort of thing long enough to "explode". They might just fall over dead, and their corpse explode some time later.

#### Option 2

Using a somewhat looser definition of "explode", the victim is injected with an agent that causes their insides to break down into gaseous byproducts, sort of like yeast on steroids. They will experience uncomfortable bloating and will eventually "pop" like a balloon. If the gas is hydrogen and/or methane, and/or if alcohol is *also* produced, you *might* be able to achieve ignition as well, although you probably won't get a fuel/air mixture suitable for rapid combustion.

---

Neither strikes me as *particularly* scientific, but it sounds like you're operating more on Rule of Comedy than realism...

Comment: Ignition isn't required. It would be a high explosive, detonations can be spontaneous. Everyone knows that jostling nitroglycerin is a gamble, what would it mean that the jar was jostling itself as it shuffled along on a hike? Any unstable high explosive should suffice here. But it has to be one that is somehow biologically viable that the person doesn't die long before they've built up enough to explode (no idea what that'd be). Also, we probably need at least tens of grams of the substance (if not more).

Answer (score 5):

- You're bitten
- Slowly over the next few days get fatigue and cramps
- Start craving bananas. They help a bit.
- See a doctor. Doctor runs tests. Doctor notices a potassium deficiency.
- You take supplements.
- After a few weeks, one day you start feeling really thirsty. Drink a tonne of water.
- ... And [this happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjItuyiizlQ)

As a result of being bitten, something started growing under your stomach. It leeches the potassium from your body. You put extra in in the form of supplements. Eventually it starts triggering crazy thirst, when your stomach is full of water, the thing punctures your stomach, letting water and potassium combine.

(If you need to explain "but why does it grow"? I think bugs reproductive cycle is the best bet. Those baby bugs need their potassium to grow, pity us humans give us supplements and overdo it)

Comment: That happens with metallic potassium, not with the organic forms that already are more or less oxidised.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

If you are allergic to bees and they sting you, you are at serious risk of dying. If you can't get medicated, you will surely perish.

In real life, unnatended corpses can explode due to gas buildup in the intestines. [This is very well documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploding_animal). This is common for cows, whales and [humans](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/7b775g/how-to-avoid-being-an-exploding-corpse-814) (specially when the corpse is mishandled pre-burial).

So, to summarize:

1. Get stung and die for want of an epipen
2. Explode
3. ????
4. Profit!

Answer (score 2):

> However, I would like to have some plausible science back-up (maybe slightly far-fetched) of a bug sting that induces body explosion.

I am sorry, but there isn't one. "Explosion" means a high energy density, and you don't have that in the human body. The best you can do is, and even that is disputed, get enough energy from the body to burn said body (so-called "spontaneous human combustion").

There is [a SF novel where a unhealthy diet caused this kind of troubles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185063/book-about-man-destroying-earth-via-pollution-environmental-disasters), and you might perhaps imagine a parasite whose lifecycle involved creating compressed methane-air mix (grisou) cysts in the intestine. There are stranger things in nature - I still shudder remembering how [*Sacculina carcini*](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2013/10/parasitic-sacculina-bends-host-will/) reproduces itself.

You can have a **really** far-fetched explanation - for that, you need an *alien* bug, since there's no way our critter evolved in Earth ecosystems.

The bug is the result of a really weird arms race between, well, alien bugs. The need to protect its offspring and allow it to develop required the bug to store more and more energetic nutrients into its eggs - less and less eggs, until this particular bug only deposited the one egg. But the energy content of the egg made it an ideal prey.

So this bug developed a different strategy, depositing a smaller egg beneath the bark of a local hardy shrub. The egg started developing an intermediate stage, intercepting the sugary plant juices and, in time, constructing a bomb-proof shell and a bomb outside it. The purpose of the bomb is dual: first, letting the pupa go free from the host shrub. Second, providing a suitable area for the newborn to scavenge some food, all local competition having been likely killed.

When embedded into a human being, the egg proceeds the same way, except faster thanks to the richer fluids and higher temperature. Energy is harvested from blood sugars, and when the young is ready to be born, KABOOM.

Answer (score 2):

**2 hypotheses**

1. Inject modified gut microbes

---

Others have pointed out that many archaea in our gut already produce methane. If the sting were to inject a slightly modified version of *Methanobrevibacter smithii* that could feed off of human fat rather than digested sugars, it would create a methane build-up around the stinging site which could then cause an explosion. Suspension of disbelief can accelerate the plausible speed at which the bacteria produce methane and the explosion should be large enough to send chunks of person flying in all directions.

2. The Wick effect

---

This is an actual hypothesis to explain spontaneous human combustion that I have slightly modified to account for the situation. Unfortunately, the victim will erupt in flames rather than really explode but it's still gruesome.

Basically, if the sting breaks open one of your subcutaneous fat reserves while stinging you and then sets fire to it, your clothes will absorb said fat and it will act as a wick of which you are the candle. All you see from the outside is a bug sting someone and then flames start immediately spreading out from the wound and quickly wrap the entire body in flames until all that is left are calcinated bones.

The advantage with this one is that its the only scenario where the effects are really immediate (all other explanations would require a slow build-up of combustive material) and it still offers a spectacular demise for it's victim.

Answer (score 1):

[***Spontaneous Human Combustion***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_human_combustion):

As weird as it sounds, this is a phenomenon that has been studied and has at least a little plausibility to it. People have some very weird accounts of bursting into flame and burning up without a clear reason. While a lot of folks think it is crazy, it fits well with your insect model.

An insect with a venom that is filled with catalyst could cause a chemical reaction to start in a susceptible person generating more chemical energy than it needs to continue. A protein enzyme is not ideal (proteins denature in heat), but it could start off the process. Otherwise, the catalyst could be something like a metal needed in reactions that is normally critically short. I don't know that your setting is, so the people there could be slightly different and uniquely vulnerable to this phenomenon.

If you need an actual explosion, there are a variety of organic volatiles that can be produced (like methane), and if gut bacteria react strongly with whatever is in that sting, they produce methane in abundance. With the heat of spontaneous human combustion added, you could have an explosion (but I doubt a big one).